# Get the formatting of a table that a specific string of text exisits in and create a new table with the same formatting

Tags: c#, openxml, document

Using OpenXML in C#, we need to:

1. Find a specific string of text on a Word document (**this text will always exist in a table cell**)
2. Get the formatting of the text and the table that the text exists in.
3. Create a new table with the same text and table formatting while pulling in text values for the cell from a nested List

This is the code that I currently have and the places I am not sure how do:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileWordFile, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
    Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;
    IEnumerable paragraphs = body.Elements<Paragraph>();
    Paragraph targetParagraph = null;
    //Comment 1: Loop through paragraphs and search for a specific string of text in word document
    foreach (Paragraph paragraph in paragraphs) {
        if(paragraph.Elements<Run>().Any()) {
            Run run = paragraph.Elements<Run>().First();
            if(run.Elements<Text>().Any()) {
                Text text = run.Elements<Text>().First();
                if (text.Text.Equals("MY SEARCH STRING")) {
                    targetParagraph = paragraph;
                    // Comment 2: How can I get the formatting of the table that contains this text??

                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Comment 3: Create table with same formatting as where the text was found
    Table table1 = new Table();
    TableProperties tableProperties1 = new TableProperties();
    //Comment 4: How can I set these properties to be the same as the one found at "Comment 2"??


    wordDoc.Close();
    wordDoc.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for text elements that are inside a table cell, you can use a LINQ query to get there quickly without needing to use a heap of nested loops.

```
// Find the first text element matching the search string 
// where the text is inside a table cell.
var textElement = body.Descendants<Text>()
                      .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Text == searchString && 
                                           t.Ancestors<TableCell>().Any());
```

Once you have your match, the easiest way to duplicate the containing table with all its formatting and contents is simply to clone it.

```
if (textElement != null)
{
    // get the table containing the matched text element and clone it
    Table table = textElement.Ancestors<Table>().First();
    Table tableCopy = (Table)table.CloneNode(deep: true);

    // do stuff with copied table (see below)
}
```

After that, you can add things to the corresponding cell of the copied table.  It's not entirely clear what you meant by "pulling in text values for the cell from a nested List" (what list?  nested where?), so I'll just show a contrived example.  (This code would replace the "do stuff" comment in the code above.)

```
    // find the table cell containing the search string in the copied table
    var targetCell = tableCopy.Descendants<Text>()
                              .First(t => t.InnerText == searchString)
                              .Ancestors<TableCell>()
                              .First();

    // get the properties from the first paragraph in the target cell (so we can copy them)
    var paraProps = targetCell.Descendants<ParagraphProperties>().First();

    // now add new stuff to the target cell
    List<string> stuffToAdd = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "baz", "quux" };
    foreach (string item in stuffToAdd)
    {
        // for each item, clone the paragraph properties, then add a new paragraph
        var propsCopy = (ParagraphProperties)paraProps.CloneNode(deep: true);
        targetCell.AppendChild(new Paragraph(propsCopy, new Run(new Text(item))));
    }
```

Lastly, you need to add the copied table to the document somewhere or you won't see it.  You don't say in your question where you would want this to appear, so I'll just put it at the end of the document.  You can use methods like `InsertAfter`, `InsertAt`, `InsertBefore`, etc. to insert the table relative to other elements.

```
    body.AppendChild(tableCopy);
```

Hope this helps.